# Computer freezes within a few minutes of normal mode; works great in safe mode with networking

Tags: windows-7

I was browsing a news website and the computer froze after I clicked on a link.  I waited about ten minutes, still "processing" and decided to restart.  After restarting, I got the same problem within a couple of minutes of restarting, this time while trying to open a PDF file.  This happened several times, but when I restarted in safe mode with networking, everything works great.

I ran Malwarebytes anti-malware and it found a few things, but restarting in normal mode I got the same problem again.  I ran Malwarebytes again in safe mode, and even more stuff was found, but again, restarting in normal mode the freezing issue reoccurred.  I have tried a bunch of anti-Virus scans from safe mode, since running Symantec in normal mode does not work (it starts, but then a few minutes later when the freezing happens, the scan cannot continue) with a few different companies, but either nothing is found, or a few things are found, deleted, and then restarting in normal mode does not show any improvement.

I am convinced there is a virus lurking but I can't seem to clear it out.  What should I do?

Comment: Its unlikely a virus is lurking because, your computer locking up, a virus author normally wants their work to run undetected. If you boot into a mimimal configuration ( this isn't safe mode ) does this still happen?  Additionally what was found exactly?  When you attempt this test, disable synmantec, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to Restart your Computer in safemode with command prompt. Once you are there,

Type this command and hit enter

rstrui.exe

System Restore window will popup, Now restore your computer to a previous data when it worked fine. System Restore will execute without any interruption as no other process will take place except it.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to mention that this was the first thing I tried.  It was going for about 30-40 minutes but then after the computer restarted I got a prompt saying that the system restore failed.  Granted, I only tried this once, so after the latest anti-virus scan, I'll give it another try.

Comment: I suggest you to do it through safe mode once. It prevents any interruption that a virus could cause in normal mode

Comment: @Sam, then please edit your question and mention this